# Manage types of responses from the server

Tags: json, android-studio, http, server, android-volley

I am confused and I hope that you can help me resolve this doubt, I am working with the POST method hand in hand with the Volley library, the server brings me two types of answers.

**The first**

If the user enters correctly his data the server has to throw me the user's data. As exemplified below.

[Result of the user's request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvJWq.png)

This is how the request is sent to the server from the code.

```
 public void getData() {

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlLogin,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        System.out.print(jsonResponse);



                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(e));
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(error));
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
        }

        // here is params will add to your url using post method
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Email", edtEmail.getText().toString());
            params.put("Password", edtPassword.getText().toString());
            return params;
        }
    };

    postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            10000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(postRequest);
    DiskBasedCache cache = new DiskBasedCache(this.getCacheDir(), 500 * 1024 * 1024);
    requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack()));
    requestQueue.start();
}
```

Up to this point everything works great, the problem arises when you enter some data wrong because the server does not answer anything in obsolute.

Information that is. It should show if the user enters some erroneous information.

[Result when entering erroneous information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8eha.png)

The problem I have is that when you send those or other wrong data the server does not respond to me with any type of data, it only goes directly Response.ErrorListener ()

```
new Response.ErrorListener() { //com.android.volley.ServerError
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(error));
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
```

After passing the debug for that error, the message "The application is running" continues, thank you in advance and I hope you can help me resolve the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to design base architecture of Volley.
Like you need to create one Base class for every request you made to server

```
abstract class BaseJSONRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
```

in this base BaseJSONRequest you need to Override methods of Volley Request class

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
and this below
@Override
public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
```

then you need to extend this BaseJSONRequest for every request you made to server
i give you one example below.

```
public class LoginRequest extends BaseJSONRequest<User> {

private final String mUserNamePassword;
private final String mpassword;

public LoginRequest(String userName, String password, boolean byPin, String deviceId, Callback<User> callback) {
    super(Method.GET, NetworkController.URL_LOGIN, createParams(byPin, deviceId), callback);
}

private static HashMap<String, String> createParams(boolean byPin, String deviceId) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    return map;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

}


@Override
protected User parseData(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    try {

        System.out.println("-Login Request--"+jsonObject);

        return new User(jsonObject.getJSONObject("user"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}